# Subir varias imágenes utilizando una subconsulta (OPENROWSET)

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente query:

```
SELECT 'imagen.png', 
       dbo.ConvertToBase64(BULKCOLUMN)
       FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\\imagen.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS DOCUMENT
```

Esto me permite con facilidad en SQL SERVER tener un archivo imagen y rápidamente a través de una función convertirla al formato Base64. (Este es mi propósito).

Para subir una imagen harcodeada no tengo problemas pero tengo una tabla temporal con varios nombres de archivos que necesito que pasen por este SELECT.

El inconveniente que veo es que la sentencia FROM ya está siendo utilizada por OPENROWSET.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mi problema es que quiero que "'C:\\imagen.png'" sea dinamico, es decir, que se obtenga de una tabla temporal ya cargada con paths y nombres.